# Pandas does not recognize NaN values on M1 macbook pro

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan, apple-m1

Pandas on m1 macbook pro is not recognizing NaN values even though NaN values apparently exist in the data.
[The first picture shows the first 5 rows of the data, and you can apparently see that there are NaN values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWPPj.png)

[In the second picture, however, when I do data.info() which prints out Non-Null count of each column, it says that there is no null values for any column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4KtW.jpg)

When I run the same code on Windows and Linux (haven't tried it on macbooks without the m1 chip), they correctly recognize the NaN values.
I've tried it on two different m1 chip macboooks, but same result.
Anyone having the same problem?? or know what might be causing this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Consider submitting an issue to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: @Stuart just did. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data.info()
```

to see what type of variable they are in the dataframe. My guess is that nothing in that column is being recognised as a number.

Comment: Please take a look at the second picture (in blue and underlined link) in the original post.
You can see that every column is recognized as either dtype int64 or float64.